# Where to call filter for ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment, android-filterable

I'm working on a homework planner app, and I'm looking for a way to display only certain elements in an ArrayList that holds Task objects. After the user clicks on a course from a list of course titles, the list of tasks that pertain to that course should be displayed. Currently, it shows a list of all tasks, no matter which course has been selected. Each Task object stores the course that it belongs to, in a field called mBelongsToCourse. I created a Filter in my TaskAdapter to filter by course name, but I don't know where to call it to make it work. I've searched for answers to this issue extensively on here, but in every case where someone is filtering an ArrayAdapter, it seems like the filter is responding to some user input such as a search. In my case, the user input is just the intent extra of the course name when the user selects a course, which starts an intent to show my TaskListFragment, but should only show tasks for that course.

Below is my TaskListFragment Class, which includes the TaskAdapter and TaskFilter:

```
public class TaskListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Task> mTasks;
private  static String courseName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    courseName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    getActivity().setTitle(courseName);
    mTasks = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTasks();

    TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Get the Task from the adapter
    Task t = ((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
    // Start TaskActivity with this task
    //Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskPagerActivity.class);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(TaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID, t.getId());
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_task_list, menu);
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_new_task:
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setBelongsToCourse(courseName);
        Log.d("yoyo", "belongsToCourse was set as: " + task.getBelongsToCourse());
        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).addTask(task);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(TaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID, task.getId());
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.task_list_item_context, menu);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                long id, boolean checked) {
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }

        // ActionMode.Callback methods
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.task_list_item_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_delete_task:
                TaskAdapter adapter = (TaskAdapter)getListAdapter();
                TaskLab taskLab = TaskLab.get(getActivity());
                for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
                        taskLab.deleteTask(adapter.getItem(i));
                    }
                }
                mode.finish();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position;
    TaskAdapter adapter = (TaskAdapter)getListAdapter();
    Task task = adapter.getItem(position);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_delete_task:
        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).deleteTask(task);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<Task> taskList;
    private Filter taskFilter;

    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, tasks);
        this.taskList = tasks;
        this.taskFilter = new TaskFilter();
        getFilter().filter(courseName);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, null);
        }

        // Configure the view for this Task
        Task t = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(t.getTitle());
        TextView dateTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_dateTextView);
        dateTextView.setText(t.getDate().toString());
        CheckBox completedCheckBox =
                (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_completedCheckBox);
        completedCheckBox.setChecked(t.isCompleted());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (taskFilter == null)
            taskFilter = new TaskFilter();
        return taskFilter;
    }

    private class TaskFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering (CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null | constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.values = taskList;
                results.count = taskList.size();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Task> newTaskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
                for (Task t : taskList) {
                    if (t.getBelongsToCourse().toUpperCase().equals(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        newTaskList.add(t);
                    }
                }
                results.values = newTaskList;
                results.count = newTaskList.size();
            } return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                taskList = (ArrayList<Task>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have been trying to solve this problem for far too long, and I'm still completely lost.

EDIT: I've taken out everything to do with my original Filter, and am instead using this method in my TaskAdapter:

```
public ArrayList<Task> filterTasks() {
     ArrayList<Task> filteredTasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
     for (Task t: taskList) {
          if (t.getBelongsToCourse().equals(courseName)) {
               filteredTasks.add(t);
          }
     } return filteredTasks;
}
```

To filter the tasks. In the onCreate method of TaskListFragment, I've added the middle line below:

```
TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
adapter.filterTasks();
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I've also made LogCat print out the list of tasks in filteredTasks (still in the onCreate method). So when I click on a course, add a task, then go back to the TaskListFragment, I get a printout of the tasks that belong to that course. And the lists are staying separate for each course! This is great progress for me so far after muddling through trying to do this for the past week and seeing no results. Still, though, I'm seeing all of the tasks on every course page, not the filtered tasks. Is this just an issue of my listView not updating?

Comment: *which starts an intent to show my TaskListFragment,* - send to your `TaskListFragment`(through a Bundle when it's created) the target course and pass this to the `TaskAdapter` class. In the `TaskAdapter`'s constructor  simply filter the tasks list. You don't need to implement the `Filter` if you don't want to change the adapter as it's used(which doesn't seem to be your case as you want to filter(only once?) when the fragment is first shown).

Comment: Hi Luksprog, thanks so much for your answer! Currently I'm sending an intent extra from my CourseListFragment to TaskListFragment that is the name of the course that has been clicked on. So I should also pass this to my TaskAdapter? Currently since they're all in the same class, the field that holds the course name can be accessed by TaskAdapter, and I've tried filtering the results directly in the constructor, but still, I get the full list of tasks no matter which course I click on.

Comment: Is there any way you could give me more detailed instructions on what I should be doing, because I feel like I must just be overlooking some important aspect that I haven't realized because I'm new to android.

Comment: If you use a BaseAdapter (for more flexibility) there is a filter system you can overrride getFilter() and implement Filterable https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onCreate method you pass all the tasks of the previous Activity on to your Adapter then set it to your ListView, why don't you filter your tasks before passing them to the adapter? the heavy work should be done in a different thread though to avoid blocking the UI for too long, show a progressDialog when you start initializing the List and when it's filtered hide it.

I mean if you inflate the ListView, set it's Adapter to it with the list that contains all tasks, if you want to modify the List after initializing you should do it before setting the Adapter, to avoid putting extra items on it. If you still want to do it so, apply the filter to the task list, then call notifyDataSetChanged() for the Adapter to change items. IMHO I would change the List of Tasks before passing it to the Adapter to avoid this. If you have UI freezing use a different thread.

Comment: Ok, I've taken out everything to do with my Filter, and made a method in TaskAdapter to filter the tasks by course name. Then in my onCreate method in TaskListFragment, I've added the middle line below:
TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
adapter.filterTasks();
setListAdapter(adapter);

Is this what you meant? I shouldn't need to call notifyDataSetChanged() if I'm getting rid of the actual Filter, right?

Comment: You're getting closer. Putting this method in the Adapter will block the UI, put it in another thread if you see that the UI freezes. I am a very perfectionist developer, I would put that method in another class or as a private method inside TaskListFragment, I really don't see the Adapter class as its place...but yeah, in essence that's what I meant. If it solves your question mark my answer as correct please.

Comment: Ok, I moved the filterTasks() method into TaskListFragment.
And in my onCreate(), modified it for this:
ArrayList<Task> filteredTaskList = filterTasks(mTasks);
TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(filteredTaskList);

But now, my TaskListFragment isn't showing any tasks. LogCat confirms the tasks are being saved, but nothing shows up under any of the courses. I've tried doing it this way before, and got stuck with the fact that no tasks show up.

Comment: Okay, scratch what I just said about no tasks showing up. It is working perfectly, but not until I go back to the course list and select the course again. Then the filtered tasks appear. Is there any way I can make them show up the first time I return to the TaskListFragment? Thanks so much for your help already, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: You should create the ArrayList filteredTaskList as an object first with the constructor. When you filter the tasks you don't modify all the task list don't you? that object should be final so it's never modified. When you ask if you can make the tasks show up the first time you return to the TaskListFragment what do you mean? pressing the back button? clicking on a course list item?